# Удаление ссылок по регулярному выражению

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно удалить ссылки ввида |yadi.sk/d/nWUe0X9bHukZf|. они меняются. Общее только yadi.sk/d оставив ||

Comment: Всё для ответа на вопрос должно быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылке. Если надо составить регулярку, то добавьте метку [tag:регулярные-выражения] и прочитайте её описание: надо привести однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Алексей, а можно пример пожалуйста?

Comment: ссылка к тому же заблокирована.

Comment: Нужно удалить найти и заменить ссылки. которые начинаются на yadi.sk/d/dasddasd как пример. единственное что общее это yadi.sk/d/ на пробел

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример (3-5) строк, в которых ссылка подлежит удалению, и пару похожих (имеющих аналогичные фрагменты, но не ссылки), которые не должны измениться. для каждой строки покажите её конечное состояние. И обязательно укажите точную версию MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

А я не понимаю, причем здесь регулярные выражения.

По моему, довольно простое SQL выражение `DELETE FROM url_table WHERE url LIKE 'https://yadi.sk/d/%' ;` вполне решает проблему.

Здесь мы используем оператор LIKE и выражение, в котором начало фиксировано `https://yadi.sk/d/`, а за этим фиксированным началом может идти что угодно, о чем нам говорит оператор `%`.

Это, если угодно, "регулярные выражения для бедных" в самом SQL. Нет, даже не так: для совсем бедных.

Тем не менее, задачу это вполне себе решает.

**Дополнение**

В комментарии автор вопроса прислал картинку с php my admin'ом.

На этой картинке видно, как я понимаю,

1. что таблица называется dle_post
2. что вопрос сформулирова неверно: автору надо не удалить строки, которые содержат ссылку на я-диск, а проапдейтить строки, так, чтобы ссылки в этой строке не стало.

То есть: было `мусор - мусор - мусор |я-диcк| - мусор2 - мусор3 и т.п.`, а стало просто `мусор - мусор - мусор || - мусор2 - мусор3 и т.п.`

3. что поле в таблице dle_post, котрое надо апдейтить, называется xfields

Если всё это - верно, то алгоритм такой:

1. запросом SELECT * FROM dle_post WHERE xfields LIKE '%|https://yadi.sk/d/%|%' находим строки.
2. анализируем поле xfields, чтобы понять, где в нём начинается ссылка. В SQL это делается выражением POSITION("|https://yadi.sk/d/" in xfields)
3. теперь надо найти конец ссылки - ведь она, как я понял, не фиксированной длинны. Это делается той же POSITION, только искать надо правый ограничитель "|".
4. вот теперь есть 2 позиции: начало и конец ссылки. Теперь её можно вырезать, воспользовавшись SUBSTR и склеиванием строк.
5. и наконец, надо выполнить UPDATE.

Алгоритм я написал, теперь его надо превратить в одно, хоть и сложное, выражени ена SQL. Ну - тут вам и карты... то есть, google в  руки.

Или - можно примерно так же написать это на PHP, если это для вас привычно. Алгоритм тото же, просто что то может быть попроще.

Comment: черт побери, мне только после пятого перчитываня вопроса пришло в голову, что "https://yadi.sk/d/y6P0ZdKHcsgN6" - это не пример  того, как должна выглядеть ссылка, которую надо удалить, а ссылка на внешний ресурс, который нало ОТКРЫТЬ чтобы понять, что автор имел в виду... ужос.

Comment: Или всё таки это пример того, как долдна выглядеть удаляемая ссылка?

Comment: Нужно удалить найти и заменить ссылки. которые начинаются на yadi.sk/d/dasddasd как пример. единственное что общее это yadi.sk/d/ на пробел

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YinM0j6.png
у меня вот так. мне нужно удалить ссылки ввида |http://yadi.sk/d/nWUe0X9bHukZf|. они меняются. Общее только http://yadi.sk/d/
оставив ||

Comment: не помогло https://i.imgur.com/IZZBbgZ.png

Comment: А можете пожалуйста помочь. написать этот код. я не силен просто. а по вашему примеру я буду учиться

Comment: Я Вас понимаю, но, к сожалению, сам сейчас пишу срочную задачу.. немного из другой области. Но, если Вы немного облегчите жизнь людям, и приведете несколько примеров данных (строки из dle_post, в некотрых из которых есть ссылка, а в других - нет) - может, еще кто то Вам сможет помочь?